# Hot water stops flowing after clunking noise

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

When I turn the hot water on in the bathroom faucet, a clunking noise sounds, and the water stops flowing.  If I open the faucet quickly, it happens immediately.  If I open the faucet slowly, it takes 20-30 seconds before the noise sounds and the water stops.  What causes this and how can it be repaired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the shut off valve 1 additional revolution fixed the problem.  It was only open one revolution, which apparently wasn't enough.  I can recreate the problem by opening the valve only partially, so it doesn't seem to be a physical blockage.  Perhaps air is involved somehow. If anyone can explain why having the valve only partially opened would lead to blockage, I'm curious about potential explanations.

Comment: Congratulations....  I really don't know what it could be other than a hammer type situation.  I would have thought you would have had a reduced flow, not a shut off.  Of course, while the faucet is turned off, the partially opened valve would allow enough water to pass the pressurize at the faucet and blast out, then reduce to what the partially open valve would allow.  Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like it could be the cartridge slipping off the shaft and closing off the water supply.  Not at all sure on this, but be worth removing the cartridge or taking a look at the washer/ O ring carrier.  If this is a newer fixture, you can buy a new cartridge, if older and the shaft is broken or stripped, it may be time for a new faucet set.  The only way to really know is to open it up and take a look.  **Make sure to turn off the water supply first!**

Comment: The faucet is less than a year old.  Will try the cartridge and let you know.  Thanks.